# after filling username and password when i press an enter button unable to login in ie but google chrome is working fine. how come?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am developing a project in asp.net in sharepoint application.
I am facing some peculiar problem.
In my login page i have 2 textbox username and password
On filling the username and password field i press enter 
As usual in most of the application we are able to login when the credentails are okay.
So i am also able to login but the issue is that in google chrome is working fine.
But in internet explorer after pressing the enter key nothing is happening the submit button is not fired where as in google chrome its working fine
why so ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0):

I didn't sure if your code is broken or doesn't submit the form if next input is submit after the textbox.

Meanwhile You can write a javascript funcion on Keypress of Input text. When keyCode 13 happen you can submit the form through Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to implement the second option. But Mr. Gupta i wonder why its not working in ie whereas working fie in google chrome